# The vote button disappeared if I voted a question/answers without signing up

Tags: bug, design, voting

Today, I see this question on the [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) site. [Command for Multiplying Integers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712967/command-for-multiplying-integers)

I want to upvote the answers.

1. I click the upvote.

   > [image]
2. Oops, I forgot  I didn’t even sign up an account for that site.
3. Click the cross.

   > [image]
4. Has the upvote is disappeared? The arrow stays white, becoming invisible on the white background.

   [image]

I felt curious when the upvote disappeared. I did the same thing for the downvotes and the vote button for it disappeared. Later, the same thing happened for that question if I click upvote or downvote and the vote button disappeared. The arrow still stay white for it. Weird!

Comment: The report is not 100% the same but I'm sure it has the same root cause and are therefor the same bug.

Comment: @rene I think I will not close this question myself first. Maybe wait for the staff reply.

Comment: @rene is correct. It does have the same root cause. We are looking into it.